# Closing SearchView suggestion when touched outside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-search

I have `RecyclerView` items when search view is expanded I show search suggestions but when user taps outside i.e on the parent layout
`RecyclerView` item receives the click and takes to detail activity which I don't want to happen. If search suggestions are visible and tapped outside
it should close search suggestion and `RecyclerView` item shouldn't receive item click.

Comment: check the search view when clicking the item

Comment: @VV, Didn't get what you meant ?

Comment: code plz.......

Comment: for each item click. please cheat the content in the search view

Comment: I tried that, but I have ads as well for which I don't have the control. I am looking for something where I can make parent layout lose focus when search view is expanded and when tapped on parent layout it receives focus and search suggestion gets closed.

Comment: show me the code.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried that, but I have ads as well for which I don't have the control. I am looking for something where I can make parent layout lose focus when search view is expanded and when tapped on parent layout it receives focus and search suggestion gets closed.

Just try the opposite.

On RecyclerView Item click check if SearchView is focused. If so, clear SearchView focus instead of perform RecyclerView Item click.

Example:

```
if (mSearchView.hasFocus()) mSearchView.clearFocus();
else performRecyclerViewItemClick();
```

PS: I cannot comment since I'm new here.